# Is there any way to detect error in windows batch file? (c++ code compilation)

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, compilation

I have written the run.bat file to compile as well as run my c++ code through the windows terminal.
The file contains only two commands:

1. g++ %1.cpp -o %1.exe
2. %1.exe

But I can't figure out how to stop the execution of the second command if the code has some compile-time errors. Is there any solution available? Please let me know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read many blogs and I came up with this solution.

```
g++ %1.cpp -o %1.exe
if %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 1 exit/b
%1.exe
```

Thank you everyone for helping me :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into other ways of building.

If you have GCC then you very likely have [the `make` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) as well, and can write [*makefiles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)#Makefile) for handling dependencies and rules.

And the part that relates most to your question is that if one rule in a makefile fails, then rules further up the chain won't be executed.

---

For the system in the question we could have a simple `Makefile` such as this:

```
run: $(PROGRAM).exe
    ./$(PROGRAM).exe

$(PROGRAM).exe: $(PROGRAM).cpp
    g++ -Wall $(PROGRAM).cpp -o $(PROGRAM).exe
```

Then in the terminal you run the command

```
make run PROGRAM=my_program
```

And the `make` command will read the `Makefile`. If the source file `my_program.cpp` is newer than `my_program.exe` (or if `my_program.exe` doesn't exist) then `my_program.cpp` will be built into `my_program.exe`. Then `my_program.exe` will be executed.

Note that I don't really recommend having a "run" target like this. Instead I recommend that you separate building and running. You can do that with the command

```
make PROGRAM=my_program && ./my_program.exe
```

This is the same as the two separate commands

```
make PROGRAM=my_program
./my_program.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

For a batch-only solution, combine the two commands with `&&` which runs the second command only if the first one succeeded (and optionally add a `||` message if either command failed).

```
g++ %1.cpp -o %1.exe  &&  %1.exe  ||  echo command error
```

Comment: Note that `||` also reacts on `%1.exe` in case it is executed…

Comment: @aschipfl Right, that's what I meant by "*either command failed*".

Answer (score 0):

save it like run.cmd
and to run it you should type in console run.cmd "file_name" (without cpp extension)

```
@echo off

g++ %~1.cpp -o %~1.exe
if %errorlevel% equ 0 %~1.exe
```